# Why is Javascript hoisting this variable?

Tags: javascript

Why the freak is Javascript hoisting the variable jsonObj?!?!

If I place the `console.debug` into the `$.get` function, I can see the JSON data. Otherwise, it's an empty string.

```
function searchDirectory() {

    var jsonObj = '';
    var params = {
        'firstName':    $('input[name=firstName]').val(),
        'lastName':     $('input[name=lastName]').val()
    };

    $.get("directory-search.php", params, function (data) {
        jsonObj = JSON.parse(data);
    })
    .fail(function () {
        alert("Oops! We could not process your request. Please try again later.");
    });
    console.debug(jsonObj);
}
```

I've tried not declaring the variable at the top and letting it set the global inside the `$.get` function, but that requires that I click the button that calls this function twice the first time.

Comment: No hoisting is occurring.  The callback passed to `$.get` runs after the `console.debug` call.

Comment: @thefourtheye Sorry, I searched for an hour first. I always try to figure it out on my own. Dan D.: Thanks! I'll check out that other question for more info.

Comment: @hyperGeoMetric No problem. The duped question discusses this particular problem in detail. Trust me, its a good read :-)

Comment: @thefourtheye Thanks! It's kind of like 'der' now. I'm tired. ;)